# Problems running HelloListView in the android emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

hello i am trying to get a better grasp of the views of android
i am getting an error when i try to run the program
the program will run but it will not show anything
here is HelloListView.java

```
package com.HelloListView;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HelloListView extends ListActivity {
    private string[] coun;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter (new ArrayAdapter <string>(this, R.layout.list_item,coun));

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener (new OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext(), null, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        final String[] coun = new String[] {
            "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra",
            "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina",
            "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan",
            "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium",
            "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia",
            "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil", "British Indian Ocean Territory",
            "British Virgin Islands", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi",
            "Cote d'Ivoire", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde",
            "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China",
            "Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo",
            "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic",
            "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic",
            "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea",
            "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Faeroe Islands", "Falkland Islands", "Fiji", "Finland",
            "Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia", "France", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia",
            "French Southern Territories", "Gabon", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar",
            "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau",
            "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard Island and McDonald Islands", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary",
            "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica",
            "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos",
            "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg",
            "Macau", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands",
            "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Moldova",
            "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia",
            "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand",
            "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "North Korea", "Northern Marianas",
            "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru",
            "Philippines", "Pitcairn Islands", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar",
            "Reunion", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Sqo Tome and Principe", "Saint Helena",
            "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Pierre and Miquelon",
            "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal",
            "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands",
            "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "South Korea",
            "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "Swaziland", "Sweden",
            "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "The Bahamas",
            "The Gambia", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey",
            "Turkmenistan", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Tuvalu", "Virgin Islands", "Uganda",
            "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom",
            "United States", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan",
            "Vanuatu", "Vatican City", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Wallis and Futuna", "Western Sahara",
            "Yemen", "Yugoslavia", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"
          };
    }


}
```

here is the list_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<TextView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:padding="10dp"
 android:textSize="16sp">
</TextView>
```

thanks for your help let me know if i need to post anything else
thanks,
CS

this is my new HelloListView.java

public class HelloListView extends ListActivity {
    private string[] coun;

```
public class HelloListView extends ListActivity
{
    private string[] coun = new String[] {
            "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra",
            "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina",
            "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan",
            "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium",
            "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia",
            "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil", "British Indian Ocean Territory",
            "British Virgin Islands", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi",
            "Cote d'Ivoire", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde",
            "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China",
            "Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo",
            "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic",
            "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic",
            "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea",
            "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Faeroe Islands", "Falkland Islands", "Fiji", "Finland",
            "Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia", "France", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia",
            "French Southern Territories", "Gabon", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar",
            "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau",
            "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard Island and McDonald Islands", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary",
            "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica",
            "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos",
            "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg",
            "Macau", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands",
            "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Moldova",
            "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia",
            "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand",
            "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "North Korea", "Northern Marianas",
            "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru",
            "Philippines", "Pitcairn Islands", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar",
            "Reunion", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Sqo Tome and Principe", "Saint Helena",
            "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Pierre and Miquelon",
            "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal",
            "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands",
            "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "South Korea",
            "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "Swaziland", "Sweden",
            "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "The Bahamas",
            "The Gambia", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey",
            "Turkmenistan", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Tuvalu", "Virgin Islands", "Uganda",
            "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom",
            "United States", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan",
            "Vanuatu", "Vatican City", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Wallis and Futuna", "Western Sahara",
            "Yemen", "Yugoslavia", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"
          };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter (new ArrayAdapter <string>(this, R.layout.list_item,coun));

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener (new OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext(), null, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is this?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
final String[] coun = new String[] {
    "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra",
    "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina",
    ...
```

Remove this array and put all the values in your "private string[] coun;" variable.

```
public class HelloListView extends ListActivity {
    private String[] coun = new String[] {
    "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra",
    "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina",
    ...
```

EDIT:

This is what you should do :

```
package com;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HelloListView extends ListActivity
{
    private String[] coun = new String[] {
            "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra",
            "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina",
            "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan",
            "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium",
            "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia",
            "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil", "British Indian Ocean Territory",
            "British Virgin Islands", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi",
            "Cote d'Ivoire", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde",
            "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China",
            "Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo",
            "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic",
            "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic",
            "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea",
            "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Faeroe Islands", "Falkland Islands", "Fiji", "Finland",
            "Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia", "France", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia",
            "French Southern Territories", "Gabon", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar",
            "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau",
            "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard Island and McDonald Islands", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary",
            "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica",
            "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos",
            "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg",
            "Macau", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands",
            "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Moldova",
            "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia",
            "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand",
            "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "North Korea", "Northern Marianas",
            "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru",
            "Philippines", "Pitcairn Islands", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar",
            "Reunion", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Sqo Tome and Principe", "Saint Helena",
            "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Pierre and Miquelon",
            "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal",
            "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands",
            "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "South Korea",
            "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "Swaziland", "Sweden",
            "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "The Bahamas",
            "The Gambia", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey",
            "Turkmenistan", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Tuvalu", "Virgin Islands", "Uganda",
            "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom",
            "United States", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan",
            "Vanuatu", "Vatican City", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Wallis and Futuna", "Western Sahara",
            "Yemen", "Yugoslavia", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"
          };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter (new ArrayAdapter <String>(this, R.layout.list_item,coun));

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener (new OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext(), null, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: do i need to make a separate class

Comment: its giving me a error with the HelloListView now it is saying Multiple markers at this line
 - The type HelloListView is already 
  defined
 - Breakpoint:HelloListView

Comment: I am now getting this error "The type HelloListView is already defined"

Comment: You get this error because you declared your class twice. Your file must contain only what I wrote, remove anything else unless the imports. Are you sure you understand how Java works?

Comment: not really i am trying to learn i know very little... i am currently taking a class on java thanks for your help

Comment: No problem, so read some Java tutorials, this will really help you. If you understand Java you will have no trouble understanding Android tutorials.

Comment: I copied your code and now i am getting this error"The field HelloListView.coun is never read locally" Im sorry i dont understand this

Comment: Where would a good place to get some java tutorials? I am currently doing the total beginner course from Eclipse.

Comment: There's one tutorial from Oracle, although it may not be the best one : http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Answer (score 1):

What ever your tutorial is, you don't understand it. You overriding your member variable `coun` inside the `onCreate` and your list_view.xml is uncomplete because it can't just have a `TextView` (or you are not showing all XML files you have)... The best way to solve your problems is to start the tutorial again...

Comment: i got this tutorial from   
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

Comment: than you should start by reading it correctly... `After the onCreate() method, add the string array` does mean you shouldn't add this array *inside* the onCreate method but after it... just like LadaRaider said

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
public class ListviewSample extends Activity
{
private ListView lv1;
private String lv_arr[]={"Location1","Location2","Location3"};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
super.onCreate(icicle);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
// By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in list.
lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_arr));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going through the tutorials at the same time!  I assume you got this fixed by now but I just wanted to point out that you can just cut and paste the COUNTRIES array from the tutorial as long as you paste it before the last enclosing brace of the HelloListView class.  You don't need to make it private.

Please give me a useful feedback so that I can rate other answers!

Thanks